# Как исправить функцию， чтобы в виджете text выводились больше 3 вновь добавленных виджетов entry

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

flats = []
rw=10
def addFlat():
    global rw,k1, k2, s1, s2
    rw+=4
    p.grid(row=rw+4, column=0, sticky=W)
    p2.grid(row=rw+4, column=1, sticky=E)
    p4.grid(row=rw+6, column=1, sticky=E)
    text_1.grid(row=rw+8, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=N+E+S+W)

    k1=Label(root,text='Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:')
    k1.grid(row=rw,column=0, sticky=W)
    k2=Entry(root)
    k2.grid(row=rw,column=1, sticky=E)
    s1=Label(root,text='Введите колличество собственников:')
    s1.grid(row=rw+2,column=0, sticky=W)
    s2=Entry(root)
    s2.grid(row=rw+2,column=1, sticky=E)

    flats.append((k1, k2, s1, s2))

def deleteFlat():
    if flats:
        k1, k2, s1, s2=flats.pop()
        k1.destroy()
        k2.destroy()
        s1.destroy()
        s2.destroy()

def check():
    komun=int(kom_kv1.get())
    sobstven=int(sobs1.get())
    komun2=int(k2.get())
    sobstven2=int(s2.get())

    i=0
    j=0
    kv=int(kvar_1.get())
    letter='abcdefghlmnjipqwrtyzx'
    needLetter=letter[:sobstven]
    needLetter2=letter[:sobstven2]
    for i in range(kv+1):
        if i==0:
            continue
        elif i==komun:
            if komun<10:
                for j in needLetter:
                    spisok=((var.get()+str(v.get())+"0"+str(komun)+j+"\n")*6)
                    text_1.insert(END,spisok)
            elif komun>11:
                for j in needLetter:
                    spisok=((var.get()+str(v.get())+str(komun)+j+"\n")*6)
                    text_1.insert(END,spisok)
        elif i==komun2:
            if komun2<10:
                for j in needLetter2:
                    spisok=((var.get()+str(v.get())+"0"+str(komun2)+j+"\n")*6)
                    text_1.insert(END,spisok)
            elif komun2>11:
                for j in needLetter2:
                    spisok=((var.get()+str(v.get())+str(komun2)+j+"\n")*6)
                    text_1.insert(END,spisok)

        elif i<10:
            spisok=((var.get()+str(v.get())+"0"+str(i)+"\n")*6)
            text_1.insert(END,spisok)
        elif i>9:
            spisok=((var.get()+str(v.get())+str(i)+"\n")*6)
            text_1.insert(END,spisok)

var=StringVar()
var.set('2')
corp0=Label(root, text='Выберите корпус')
corp0.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=0, sticky=W)
corp1=Radiobutton (root, text='2', variable=var,value='2')
corp1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
corp2=Radiobutton (root, text='3', variable=var,value='3')
corp2.grid(row=1, column=1,sticky=W )

v=StringVar()
mes=Label(root,text='Выберите месяц')
mes.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
mes_1=Spinbox(root, textvariable=v, values=("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06",'07','08','09','10','11','12'))
mes_1.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

kvar=Label(root,text='Введите количество квартир:')
kvar.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
kvar_1=Entry(root,bd=2)
kvar_1.grid(row=4, column=1,sticky=W)

kom_kv=Label(root,text='Введите номер квартиры с несколькими собственниками:')
kom_kv.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
kom_kv1=Entry(root,bd=2)
kom_kv1.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

sobs=Label(root,text='Введите колличество собственников:')
sobs.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
sobs1=Entry(root,bd=2)
sobs1.grid(row=8, column=1,sticky=W )

p=Button(root,text='Добавить квартиру', command=addFlat)
p.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
p2=Button(root,text='Удалить квартиру', command=deleteFlat)
p2.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=E)

p4=Button(root,text='Вывести список', command=check)
p4.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=E)

text_1=Text(root,height=20,width=50)
text_1.grid(row=14, column=0, columnspan=3,sticky=N+E+S+W)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, напишите сначала просто для терминала, без UI, разделите код на функии, прочтите декларацию PEP8, постарайтесь оформить код и сделать его читабельным, тогда вам будет проще дать совет или помочь!

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос, скорее комментарий.